# Will there be a way to make snapshots from blockchains downloaded and maintained by nodes V0.0.1?

Tags: node

I just installed mainnet-snapshot yesterday.
I am running two nodes now, one with a mainnet node (archive) and one with the mainnet-snapshot branch (history mode=full). My baker is only connected to the mainnet node.
I was wondering if I could make a snapshot out of the mainnet node that I have been maintaining since the beginning of the betanet. I tried to use a copy of the .tezos-node/ directory from my mainnet node with the mainnet-snapshot node, however I couldn't start it and I was getting error related to the node version being 0.0.1 and not 0.0.2. 
The 2nd node using "snapshots" is gonna take otherwise forever to synchronize and download/process the whole chain.
What do you people think?

Comment: A conversion tool to take the db from 0.0.1 to 0.0.2 would be nice. I'm currently re-syncing from scratch which will take about 3 days on SSD where a conversion tool I suspect would take less than 1 hour and save a ton of bandwidth.

Comment: You will find the current answer [here](http://tezos.gitlab.io/mainnet/releases/april.html#a-lighter-setup-using-snapshots). I can't think of more than a few words to say: use mainnet branch.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tom, you just saved me a ton of time and disk space... I would have never tried to export the snapshot with the mainnet node, honestly...

Comment: Please @Tom can you post your answer as actual answer ? this way the OP can mark the question as answered

Answer (score 2):

To quote the [release notes](http://tezos.gitlab.io/mainnet/releases/april.html#a-lighter-setup-using-snapshots):

> For this purpose the mainnet node has a new command snapshot export that allows to export a snapshot from a existing whole context, in history mode full or rolling. Note that the mainnet node can only export snapshots and not import them.
>
> A node from the Git branch (or Docker tag) mainnet-snapshots is capable of importing a snapshot and starting from it. This allows for a smaller disk footprint and faster node execution because of better locality on disk. Furthermore a mainnet-snapshots node will start the testchain by default.
>
> Note that the branch mainnet-snapshots produces and requires a tezos-node directory with version 0.0.2 while a node from the branch mainnet requires version 0.0.1. The two are incompatible and a node will refuse to start if given the wrong one.